# Evaluate $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0 } \frac{(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}-e}{x}$

Tags: limits

I got this problem in my math.

Evaluate 
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} {\frac{(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}-e}{x}}$$

I tried applying the L'Hospital rule, to get
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} (1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}\frac{1}{x^2}(\frac{x}{1+x}-ln(1+x))$$
I don't know how to proceed after this.

Comment: I think this might be a plain derivative in disguise..

Comment: @CameronWilliams: Indeed

Comment: I think that the derivative of the numerator is wrong. Please check. In any manner, what freak_warrior suggested is the good way to go.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: Use $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}-e}{x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{e^{\ln{(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}}}-e}{x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{e^{\frac{\ln{(1+x)}}{x}}-e}{x}$$

Comment: Nice solution freak_warrior.........

Comment: What do I do after this?

Comment: @GTXOC: Use L'Hopital rule.

Comment: Can you give me the full solution? I am still not getting it.

Comment: Hint: Can you prove that $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln{(1+x)}}{x}=1$ @GTXOC

Answer (score 0):

You can proceed as follows
$$\lim_{x\to 0}(1+x)^{1/x}\frac{\frac{x}{1+x}-\ln(1+x)}{x^2}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 0}(1+x)^{1/x}\cdot \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{x}{1+x}-\ln(1+x)}{x^2}$$

apply L'Hospital's rule for $\frac00$ form of second limit as follows
$$=\lim_{x\to 0}(1+x)^{1/x}\cdot \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{d}{dx}\frac{x}{1+x}-\frac{d}{dx}\ln(1+x)}{\frac{d}{dx}x^2}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to 0}(1+x)^{1/x}\cdot \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}-\frac{1}{(1+x)}}{2x}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 0}(1+x)^{1/x}\cdot \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-x}{2x(x+1)^2}$$
$$=-\frac12\lim_{x\to 0}(1+x)^{1/x}\cdot \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}$$
$$=-\frac12(e)\cdot (1)$$
$$=-\frac e2$$